# How to know size of an embedded document in KB's in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with an embedded document,and the collection is my transactional collection. It's like

```
{ _id : ObjectId,
userId : ObjectId,
driverId : ObjectId,
carId : ObjectId,
trips : [{embedded data about each trip}]
}
```

Now with each trip of particular user driver and car the length of trips increases. Now what I wanted to suggest to my boss was to break this collection. Instead of having an array of embedded document have a single trip detail with each document.Which is like unrolling the whole document. Now to convince him I have to give him numbers to support my argument that if n number of trip embedded document is added the document will exceed 16MB size which is highest for a mongoDB doc and it's time-consuming to run queries in it but I don't know size of 1 embedded document so can't divide  and give some numbers. How would I go about calculating the size of one document? And whatever I am doing is it correct schema wise. As in mongoDB there are no strict rules hence my question is also a bit opinionated. Hope the community understands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) size of a document using

```
var myDocument = db.collection.findOne({_id:<some id>})
Object.bsonsize(myDocument);
```

The result is in Bytes. See [Object.bsonsize()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous) for more information.

In regards to your document schema, it depends on your application use case. Having said that, it looks like your document will not hold many trips in its current design. Also see [hybrid or bucket schema design](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#hybrid-schema-design) for another alternative.